# How to disable per-user MFA settings using Microsoft Graph PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, multi-factor-authentication

I'm rewriting all my PowerShell script from MSOnline to Microsoft Graph PowerShell.

One of my existing script below is about to disable specific user's MFA settings.

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @()
```

I can't find a way to implement in Microsoft Graph PowerShell. I checked [Update-MgUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/update-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0) page. There is no relevant arguments related to this.

Comment: It seems impossible at this moment. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1144760/functionality-for-enabling-enforcing-disabling-per